# How can I make textured tiles pick up less dirt

Tags: flooring, tile, cleaning, ceramic-tile, varnishing

After having them installed, I realized that the textured tiles that I chose pick up dirt off of shoes *extremely* easily. The dirt can be cleaned off with water and a little effort, but in order for them to look clean they'd probably need to be scrubbed daily. Removing and replacing all of the tiles will be quite expensive.

Is there any product I can use to coat the tiles so that they pick up dirt less easily? Note I don't think what I need is a sealer, as the tiles are already very stain resistant (I tested them with all kinds of stuff, ketchup, olive oil, berries, etc) its just that they get dirty extremely quickly.

Comment: Textured tiles relate to safer traction. Where is the tile located? High traffic area?  Often wet locations such as bathrooms and kitchens?

Comment: Front entrance, kitchen, hallway and bathroom

Comment: Can you provide a picture? Take it close enough to a single tile at an angle  (the tile edges are edge of picture). A better description of the texture itself?

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic, sealing may reduce some of your issues but wear may require recoating more often than normal.